# The first data line skip

Tags: c#, oledb, netezza

I wrote code to connect to the NETEZZA database. When a response is received, the first line of the result disappears, i.e. only 9 of 10 lines are displayed. I read that there are such problems with the OLEDB driver, but I could not resolve the issue myself.

I tried to add the parameter HDR = YES

```
class SQL_zapros
{
        private string connString = "Provider=NZOLEDB;Password=PASSWORD; User ID=LOGIN; Data Source=127.0.0.1; Initial Catalog=SYSTEM; Persist Security Info=True;";
        public string sqlcomm = "";


        public DataTable exeReader(string cmd, OleDbParameter[] param)
        {
            OleDbConnection oConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
            OleDbCommand oCmd;
            OleDbDataReader oReader;
            DataTable AppData = new DataTable();
            oConn.Open();
            oCmd = oConn.CreateCommand();
            oCmd.CommandText = cmd;

            try
            {
                oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (oReader.Read())
                {
                    AppData.Load(oReader);
                    oReader.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
            oConn.Close();
            return AppData;
        }
    }
```

I want to get all the rows from the database

Comment: `oReader.Read()` reads the first line of the result. If `AppData.Load` also does that then the first line of the result is ignored. To fix it remove the `if` block, just pass the reader directly.

Comment: Thanks! It's Work!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Consider marking an answer below using the check mark next to the answer you want to select. You can do this after the 15 grace period has expired (starts at the moment you post your question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`oReader.Read()` reads the first line of the result. `AppData.Load` also does that, the first line of the result is ignored. To fix it remove the `if` block, just pass the reader directly.

Also use `using` blocks when creating instances where the type implements `IDisposable`. This ensures the resources are always released even in the event of an exception.

```
public DataTable exeReader(string cmd, OleDbParameter[] param)
{
    using(OleDbConnection oConn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
    {
        DataTable AppData = new DataTable();
        oConn.Open();
        var oCmd = oConn.CreateCommand();
        oCmd.CommandText = cmd;

        try
        {
            using(var oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                AppData.Load(oReader);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
    return AppData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [OleDbDataAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter?view=netframework-4.8) instead. Try like:

```
...  
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(cmd, oConn);
    adapter.Fill(AppData);    
...
```